# what is done first balancing data or cross validation?

Tags: cross-validation, unbalanced-classes

I want to classify  imbalance data in two class and I want to use oversampling, undersampling and Synthetic data generation methods .for tuning my model i want use k-fold cross validation what should i do first? 
balancing data and then use cross validation or vice versa?

Comment: The answer is neither. You do the oversampling/undersampling within the cross validation. That is, you split the data, oversample the training set only, and leave the validation/test set alone. If you are oversampling because there is a class distribution problem, then when splitting the data use stratified sampling so that your test set is reflective of what you observe in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without addressing the question of whether over-sampling or under-sampling is an appropriate approach, over-sampling before CV will cause data-leakage, as the same data point might be present in both the CV-test and training set.